# Use Twitter API to get tweets and output to csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I already have code to scrape tweets using twitter api and output to a csv file. My problem is that:

1. I cannot add header of columns to the csv file
2. Each the row is seperated by a new line, I don't know why but I don't want it.

Sorry for I cannot post image...

My output looks like:

first row: Thu May 14 00:24:55 +0000 2015 tweets 0 ...
second row:
Third row: Thu May 14 00:24:59 +0000 2015 tweets 0 ...

Here is my code:

```
# The aim of the program is to scrape tweets from tweeter based on the keywords`
# Out put a txt file that contains tweets
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import json
import csv

ckey = xxxxxxxxxx
csecret = xxxxxxxxx
atoken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
asecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            data_json = json.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(data))
            Tweet_time = data_json["created_at"]
            Tweet_text = data_json["text"]
            Retweet_count = data_json["retweet_count"]
            Tweet_name = data_json["entities"]["user_mentions"][0]["name"]
            Tweet_screenname = data_json["entities"]["user_mentions"][0]["screen_name"]
            Tweet_fw = data_json["user"]["followers_count"]
            Tweet_fd = data_json["user"]["friends_count"]
            Tweet_st = data_json["user"]["statuses_count"]
            print Retweet_count
            f = csv.writer(open("Tweets.csv", "a+"))
            f.writerow([Tweet_time, Tweet_text, Retweet_count, Tweet_name,
                    Tweet_name, Tweet_screenname, Tweet_fw, Tweet_fd, Tweet_st])
            return True

        except BaseException, e:
            print "failed on data, " + str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


# Authorize the API
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)

auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

# Call the main function
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())

# Search based on the keywords: "Avengers" and "Captain"
twitterStream.filter(track=["Avengers", "Captain"])
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Best,
Morpheus

Comment: Just checked your code and it works for me, i.e. I don't see problem number 2, no additional carriage returns when I open "Tweets.csv". No idea what could be the difference. What version of python are you using? Can you test it again? There's also a few issues but let's clear out this one first ok?

Comment: Hey lrnzcig, thank you very much for your help. I used python 2.7.9 and I used pycharm as my IDE. I tested it again, it still give me a new line between two rows. By the way, based on what you said, I tried to run the program in cygwin, but my cygwin can not find modules, do you know why? I have added the site-packages folder to my environment variable. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. I'm also at python 2.7. Anyway the only reason I can think about is a problem with the carriage return (although I don't quite see how can you find 2 of them, I mean, sometimes the different carriage return in windows/linux have weird effects but I don't see a reason for the one you describe). If you mention cygwin you must be in Windows. (I use Mac). How do you open your output file? Can you take a look to the bytes, to check what codes you have at the end of the line? (No idea how to do it in Windows, sorry)